Generating dynamic table entries using LaTeX 3
I am creating a dynamic table from a list but I do not understand why the code below generates an extra entry...
MWE:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\FillRubricsEntry}{}{
    \seq_clear:N \l_example_tmpa_seq 
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_example_tmpa_seq {1,2,3,4,5,6}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_example_tmpa_seq {
        ##1 \\\hline
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{table}[h]
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\arraystretch}{}{1.5}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        \text{Task} \\
        \hline\hline
        \FillRubricsEntry
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Actual Result:

Expected Result:


Welcome to TeX.SX!

I guess that the entries are not always as "boring" as 1,2,3,4,5,6. Otherwise you could've used an \int_step_function:nN for equally distanced numeric data.

don't use h as the sole specifier for a float. latex will replace it anyway with ht. (I used to get a warning about this but sems to have disappeared recently.)

@Skillmon Yes its more advanced and this was just a MWE.

The issue is that whenever there is unexpandable material in a cell it's considered a valid cell, even if it doesn't print any visible material.
For instance, take a look what happens here:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
  a \\
  \relax
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


You can avoid that by using an (expandable) function that doesn't need to revert an internal state at the end of the loop (that's the case for \seq_map_inline:Nn to support nested usage). For that you'll have different options, the easiest one is most likely \seq_use:Nn:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_example_tmpa_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\FillRubricsEntry}{}{
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_example_tmpa_seq {1,2,3,4,5,6}
    \seq_use:Nn \l_example_tmpa_seq { \\ \hline } \\ \hline
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\arraystretch}{}{1.5}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        Task \\
        \hline\hline
        \FillRubricsEntry
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Another one would be to define an auxiliary to handle your lines and use that with \seq_map_function:NN:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_example_tmpa_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\FillRubricsEntry}{}{
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_example_tmpa_seq {1,2,3,4,5,6}
    \seq_map_function:NN \l_example_tmpa_seq \__example_rubics_entry:n
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__example_rubics_entry:n #1
  {
    #1 \\ \hline
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\arraystretch}{}{1.5}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        Task \\
        \hline\hline
        \FillRubricsEntry
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Both of the above result in:


Nice! Are there other expl3 commands that could be used as well? What about the \int_step_ commands? Is there a similar workaround? How do I know which functions behave as needed?

@JasperHabicht all of the currently implemented inline loops need to reset state, afaik, so all of these will be problematic. All of the function or tokens loops are unproblematic, same with the use variants. In general you're on the safe side with anything that is marked as expandable in interface3.pdf. So in this answer we could've used \clist_use:nn directly, or \clist_map_function:nN.

@cfr poor Jasper is blamed without having any fault :)

@JasperHabicht very sorry.

@cfr It's alright, nothing really happend =)

Why your example doesn't work were explained in the Skillmon's answer.
I only give another approach: to create the macro using TeX primitives only and, of course, it is expandable.
\documentclass{article}

\def\FillRubricsEntry{\freA{1,2,3,4,5,6}}
\def\freA#1{\freB#1,\end,}
\def\freB#1,{\ifx\end#1\else #1\\ \hline \expandafter\freB\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\arraystretch}{}{1.5}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        Task \\
        \hline\hline
        \FillRubricsEntry
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

